# How do I respond when someone asks, “How do you feel about {food name - pizza, bowl of…} etc.”?

Tags: american-english, colloquial-language

Question is specific to office environment. Is answering "I feel awesome" or "I would love to have that" good enough?
Also, how to respond if you are not down for it or prefer something else ? Is it okay to say - "I would rather have Y than X"? Does it sound polite?

Comment: "I feel awesome" is definitely _not_ an appropriate answer! They presumably want to know whether you would like them to order that kind of food for you, so of course it's OK to say that you would rather have something different. If you're happy with the suggestion, "Yes, that would be great", ""Yes, I'd love that" or something on those lines.

Comment: If the question is about food, then the answer is always, "I love it!"  (but maybe that's just me...)

Comment: Thanks. This helps.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for your feelings *about* something in this kind of context is really an invitation for you to describe your feelings or relationship to it. In the same way that you might describe your feelings towards a person by saying "*I love them!*" you might say the same about a type of food - "*I love it!"

Saying "I feel awesome" is a statement of how you personally feel. It isn't outward-looking. You could say of the food "***it** is awesome*", which would express that your feelings towards it are positive.

In some contexts, asking for your feelings about something can be an invitation to state your *thoughts* about it. Thoughts and feelings can be described distinctly, but there is often an overlap. 'Feelings' might be thought of as being more based on emotion than logical thought, but you could still  state facts in response to a question about your 'feelings' on a topic.